# Jquery Selector after clone and appendTo

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, appendto

I have cloning and doing appendTo to an empty area on the page. Once the new item is on the DOM, I need to do some manipulation to the newly added item.

Here is the crazy > long jquery selector string I have.

```
$("#listParticipat.jsParticipantRepeat ").clone().appendTo(".jsParticipantPlaceHolder").attr('recid', custIDNum).removeClass("jsParticipantRepeat" ).removeAttr( "id" );
```

What I would like to do is to the appendTo then store the newly added item in a VAR and then do other tasks. How can I grab the newly added item with something like:

```
var newItem = $("#listParticipat.jsParticipantRepeat ").clone().appendTo(".jsParticipantPlaceHolder"); //--does not work
```

thanks.

Comment: Define `does not work`.

Comment: You should clone, then manipulate and then append. It is much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clone, manipulate, then append.

```
// clone
var elem = $("#listParticipat.jsParticipantRepeat ").clone();

// your manipulation code here
$(elem).attr('recid', custIDNum);
$(elem).removeClass("jsParticipantRepeat");
$(elem).removeAttr( "id" );

// then append
$(".jsParticipantPlaceHolder").append(elem);
```

Comment: My answer was the same, here's a fiddle along these lines: http://jsfiddle.net/WhL7J/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your problem, because your code simply works

the only thing worth to mention here is that `appendTo` can return multiple objects. It will clone your object for every matching object

http://jsfiddle.net/FBUSp/